# VR Player for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vr, video-player

Is there any VR Player for Linux (or usable with Wine) that can

- play 360° and 180° videos (optional: and images)
- turning around using mouse
- optional: play 3D Videos either as 3D (side-by-side) or just 2D (choosing one side)
- optional: choose between 3d modes Left/Right and Top/Bottom
- optional: OpenSource

I found a player that can play 360° videos, but not 180° and afaik no 3d options and not opensource: [Kolor GoPro VR Player](http://www.kolor.com/gopro-vr-player/download/)

Comment: Although GoProVRPlayer V2.3.1 used to support Linux, the latest one does not. :¬(
http://www.kolor.com/gopro-vr-player/download/

Comment: SKYBOX VR Video Player seems to work fine with SteamVR and Proton.